# How do I parse whole text in XML Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

```
foo = <root>
<m>This is <b>bold</b> and <i>
<b>italic<br/>text</b></i>.<br/></m>
</root>

doc  = Nokogiri::XML foo
doc.xpath("//m").each {|a|
  a.children.each{|v|
   puts "#{v.name}::[#{v.text}]"
  }
}
```

How do I parse all text, in all tags inside `<m>`?

I need to produce the following output ...

```
t="This is "
b="bold"
t=" and "
i=""
b="italic"
br="<br/>"
t="text"
```

...

etc

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e98fb4e4c254883a17a2

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
require 'nokogiri'

foo = <<-EOXML
<root>
 <m>This   is <b>bold</b> and <i><b>italic<br/>text</b></i>.<br/></m>
</root>
EOXML

def pr(v)
 case v.class.to_s
  when 'Nokogiri::XML::Text'
   puts "[#{v.text}]"
  when 'Nokogiri::XML::Element'
   puts "'#{v.name.to_s}':: #{pr(v.children)}"
  when 'Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet'
   puts "#{v.children}"
  else
   puts "[-#{v.class.to_s}- #{v.to_s}]"
  end
end

doc  = Nokogiri::XML.parse foo
p foo
doc.xpath("//m").each {|a|
  a.children.each{|v|
   puts "#{v.name}::[#{v.text}]"
  }
}
```

How can I change the code above so that it uses recursion?

Comment: why would you need that if I may ask?

Comment: parse all tags and text between tags, convert xml into arrays 1 array is .text() second is a tags

Comment: I know what you want, I would want to know *why* you want that array?

Comment: to edit text between tags, delete \s+, delete some gramar errors, change UpDown letters. I nned know what is previous tag and get text. I need read xml and put some subdirectory xml, check validity, and change some data. I know is only 4 tags inside <m> : this is:  b i p and br